# conditional convergence

Tags: calculus, analysis, intuition

This is an practice question from "Advanced Calculus, Folland" Chapter 6.3, Q.2 (not HW)

I am not sure how to go about this question ::

suppose $\sum { { a }_{ n } } $  is conditionally convergent. Show that there are rearrangements of $\sum { { a }_{ n } } $ whose partial sums diverge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$

Comment: Conditionnally convergent means *not absolutely convergent*, i.e., $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| = +\infty$. Now, either the sum of positive values of $a_n$, or the sum of negative values (or both), must be $+\infty$. Then you can rearrange accordingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We construct by induction a reindexing making the sum unbounded:

Let denote by $(a_n)$ again the positive terms of the series and by $(b_n)$ the negative terms. By hypothesis we have $\sum a_n=\infty$. Let $n_1$ be the first index such that $\sum a_n>1$, so the rearrangement begin by $(a_1,\ldots,a_{n_1},b_1)$.

We add up $a_{n_2}$ such that $a_1+\cdots+a_{n_2}+b_1>2$, then we complete the rearrangement on $(a_1,\ldots,b_1,a_{n_1+1},\ldots,a_{n_2})$.

By induction on $k$, we get the arrangement $(a_1,\ldots,a_{n_k},b_k)$ such that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n_k}a_j+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}b_j>k,$$
which gives us a rearrangement  making the series divergent.